# Limitar inputs dinamicamente

Tags: php, jquery, html

Sou um pouco nova em jQuery e gostaria de saber como eu faço para limitar o tamanho dos `input` inseridos dinamicamente.

Um exemplo: no código a baixo o usuário pode inserir quantos `input`s quiser, porém eu queria que limitasse esses inserts.

E possivel fazer isso dentro do jQuery?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Adicionando linhas dinamicamente</title>
<style type="text/css" media="all">
  body{ font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif }
  #tudo{ border:#CCCCCC 1px solid;width:680px;margin:0 auto }
  .bd_titulo{
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    font-weight:bold
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  function removeCampo() {
    $(".removerCampo").unbind("click");
    $(".removerCampo").bind("click", function () {
       if($("tr.linhas").length > 1){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
       }
    });
  }

  $(".adicionarCampo").click(function () {
  novoCampo = $("tr.linhas:first").clone();
    novoCampo.find("input").val("");
    novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.linhas:last");
    removeCampo();
  });
});
</script>

</head>


<body>
<form method="post" name="frm_campo_dinamico" action="">
<div id="tudo">
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="4">


  <tr><td class="bd_titulo" width="10">Qtde</td><td class="bd_titulo">Descrição</td><td class="bd_titulo">Cor</td><td class="bd_titulo">Valor R$</td></tr>
  <tr class="linhas">
    <td><input type="text" name="qtd[]" style="text-align:center" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="descricao[]" /></td>
    <td>
      <select name="cor[]">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Selecione uma cor...</option>
        <option value="Amarelo">Amarelo</option>
        <option value="Branco">Branco</option>
        <option value="Cinza">Cinza</option>
        <option value="Verde">Verde</option>            
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="valor[]" style="text-align:center" /></td>
    <td><a href="#" class="removerCampo" title="Remover linha"><img src="images/minus.png" border="0" /></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td colspan="4">
        <a href="#" class="adicionarCampo" title="Adicionar item"><img src="images/plus.png" border="0" /></a>
    </td></tr>
  <tr>
        <td align="right" colspan="4"><input type="submit" id="btn-cadastrar" value="Cadastrar" /></td>
  </tr> 
</table>
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

segue um link para visualizar melhor: https://jsfiddle.net/78e4fznm/

Answer (score 4):

Basta usar a mesma lógica que usou ao remover o campo:

```
...
if($("tr.linhas").length > 1){
...
```

Este teste serve para remover apenas se o número de linhas for maior que um.

Veja como fica copiando a lógica para a inserção de linhas (limitei a 5 como exemplo):

```
$(".adicionarCampo").click(function () {
  if($("tr.linhas").length < 5) {
    novoCampo = $("tr.linhas:first").clone();
    novoCampo.find("input").val("");
    novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.linhas:last");
    removeCampo();
  }
});
```

Segue o fiddle alterado: https://jsfiddle.net/hgoc4p9v/

Comment: Muito Obrigada, fiquei tanto tempo pra aprender o resto que as vezes coisa simples, esquecemos rsrsrs. Muito obrigada pela ajuda.

Comment: Seja bem-vinda, é legal a hora que tiver um tempinho dar uma lidinha no [Tour] e [Help] para conhecer melhor os recursos do site.

Comment: E qual seria sintaxe se eu pegasse esse limite que está inserido em uma variavel php ?

Comment: Depende do código original. Poderia colocar `if($("tr.linhas").length < <?php echo $quantidade; ?>) {` ...

Comment: Consegui aqui Bacco, muito obrigada, coloquei uma variavel var totalCampos = <?=$XX?>; e dps chamei ela dentro do codigo , rsrs, muito Obrigada

Comment: Bacco, dx eu te pergunta, ainda aproveitando esse codigo, teria como colocar um display block ?, para aparecer todas as linhas sem ter a necessidade de um "botao" ?

Comment: O botão cria os campos na hora. Se você quer um numero fixo, compensa fazer um loop, ou montar pelo PHP. Esse código seu só faz sentido pra número variável de campos.